# rails aborted when create a new folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am meeting a rails problem.

I created a rails folder by this command

```
rails new airbnb-clone -T -d postgresql --css tailwindcss
```

And it gave me these problems

1st

```
rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
rails aborted!
```

Second

```
rails  css:install:tailwindcss
rails aborted!
```

I thought that when I used the code tailwindcss, it must automatically create the tailwindcss by rails ? So why it had these error ? Should I must install tailwindcss by hand ? Could you please give me some advices?

By the way, here is my rails and ruby v

rails -v 7.0.4
ruby -v 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Just change the argument to `tailwind` instead of `tailwindcss`:

```
rails new airbnb-clone -T -d postgresql --css tailwind
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this command, you can try. I think that's oki.

```
rails new airbnb-clone  -T -d postgresql  -c=tailwind
```